# React Native LayoutAnimation custom presets

Tags: react-native

We have predefined presets like this.

```
LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.linear);
```

But I did not found a way to use my custom presets for example with linear type and 0.1s speed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```js
LayoutAnimation.configureNext(CustomAnimation)
```

with

```js
var CustomAnimation = {
  duration: 400,
  create: {
    type: LayoutAnimation.Types.spring,
    property: LayoutAnimation.Properties.scaleXY,
    springDamping: 0.7
  },
  update: {
    type: LayoutAnimation.Types.spring,
    springDamping: 0.7
  }
}
```